# Why is the fidelity, rather than the trace distance, the standard choice to compare quantum states?

Tags: fidelity, trace-distance

I don't think it's particularly controversial to say that the "standard" way people use to compare quantum states is via the [fidelity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states). Yes, sometimes the trace distance is used as well, but it seems to me that the "canonical choice", the first one in most people's minds, is to use the fidelity.

There are several ways to give an operative meaning to the fidelity, but one that seems particularly fitting in this context is the observation that the fidelity $\mathrm F(\rho,\sigma)\equiv\|\sqrt\rho\sqrt\sigma\|_1$ between equals the [Bhattacharyya coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_coefficient) between the probability distribution resulting from measuring the states, maximised over all possible POVMs producing said distributions. Some discussion about how to interpret the classical Bhattacharyya coefficient can be found in [this stats.SE post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/296361/82418).

On the other hand, the [trace distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_distance) $D(\rho,\sigma)\equiv\|\rho-\sigma\|_1$ can also be given a rather direct operative interpretation, in that it quantifies the optimal probability to discriminate between the two states.

If the goal is to compare how close a state is to another, I would have intuitively guessed the latter choice to be more "natural": I'm quantifying the maximal probability to tell apart the two states. The Bhattacharyya coefficient, essentially the inner product of the square roots of the probability distributions, also has some geometric meaning, and I'm vaguely aware that it's related to the Fisher information or other metrological quantities, but I don't know how to directly directly connect this with the goal of quantifying closeness of states.

So, is there a clear way to justify the usage of the state fidelity over the trace distance from an operative point of view?
Of course, this might also depend on the context and for what purpose the states are being compared, and then I'm asking if there is a clear way to distinguish between situations where the fidelity is the "right" choice, and situations where the trace distance is.

Comment: Honestly, because the fidelity is much easier to work with.

Comment: The only reasonably convincing argumentation I've seen in favour of the fidelity is this presentation: https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1255785. Other justifications typically single out the trace distance as the "right" metric to use between the two.

Comment: I would say it's quite the opposite. The trace distance has an operational interpretation as the maximum success probability of distinguishing two states in a quantum hypothesis testing experiment (see, e.g., Wilde Sec. 9.1.4 https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1445)

Comment: @keisuke.akira which statement are you referring to exactly? I agree with your operational interpretation for the trace distance, which is also included in the question itself.

Comment: @MateusAraújo I wonder how much that is actually the case though. Are you saying for anlytical or numerical purposes? Numerically, unless you stick to pure states, the trace distance requires to compute a single diagonalisation, vs the fidelity which requires two (at least using standard methods).

Comment: Both numerically and analytically. The most common use case of fidelity is between a mixed state and a pure state (the mixed state is the one you have and the pure the one you want). For that you don't need any diagonalization. Analytically, it is very easy to calculate the average fidelity over some group, which is why so many papers use average fidelity as a figure of merit.